# VBA : Run a macro FOR another workbook (not from)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook (A) in which I have one module with one subroutine. The subroutine downloads an excel file (workbook(B)) from the internet and opens it. The problem I'm faced with is finding a way to execute a subroutine in workbook (B) from the sub in workbook (A).

To reiterate, I have my desired subroutine **only** in workbook (A) and wish to apply it to workbook (B) by use of the sub in workbook (A).

Note: In my code workbook (B) = Nuance Mobility JIRA.xls and the desired subroutine in workbook (B) that needs to be executed is removeColumns().

My code can be found below :

```
Public Sub DL()

Dim WebUrl As String
Dim x As Workbook
Dim z As Workbook
Dim nmjexcel As String
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application

' I check to see if the file exists and delete it if it does
nmjexcel = "C:\Users\" & [A2] & "\Downloads\Nuance Mobility JIRA.xls"

If Len(Dir(nmjexcel)) <> 0 Then
    SetAttr nmjexcel, vbNormal
    Kill nmjexcel
End If

'I open chrome and download the file from an URL
WebUrl = [J1]
Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -url " & WebUrl)


Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:3"))

'I create a new 'hidden' excel app and open workbook (B)
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
xlApp.Visible = False

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\" & [A2] & "\Downloads\Nuance Mobility JIRA.xls")

' I delete some rows, a picture and some columns. 
' It's here that i would like my other subroutine, removeColumns(), to take place !

With x.Sheets("general_report")

    .Rows("1:3").Delete
    .Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1")).Delete
    .Cells.UnMerge
    .Range("A:A,D:D,E:E,F:F,H:H,I:I,J:J,K:K,L:L,M:M,N:N,O:O,P:P").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

End With

'Then I copy whats left and paste it into workbook (A)
Set z = ThisWorkbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

x.Sheets("general_report").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy

z.Sheets(1).Range("A13").PasteSpecial xlValues


x.Save
x.Application.CutCopyMode = False
x.Close

End Sub
```

My desired sub to be executed is the following

```
Sub removeColumns()

Dim rng As Range 'store the range you want to delete
Dim c 'total count of columns
Dim I 'an index
Dim j 'another index
Dim headName As String 'The text on the header
Dim Status As String 'This vars is just to get the code cleaner
Dim Name As String
Dim Age As String
Dim sht As Worksheet

Rows("1:3").Delete


Key = "Key"
Summary = "Summary"
Status = "Status"
Set sht = Sheets("general_report")

sht.Activate 'all the work in the sheet "Incidents"
c = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
'From A1 to the left at the end, and then store the number
'of the column, that is, the last column
j = 0 'initialize the var
For I = 1 To c 'all the numbers (heres is the columns) from 1 to c
    headName = Cells(1, I).Value
    If (headName <> Key) And (headName <> Summary) And (headName <> Status) Then
    'if the header of the column is differente of any of the options
        j = j + 1 ' ini the counter
        If j = 1 Then 'if is the first then
            Set rng = Columns(I)
        Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, Columns(I))
        End If
     End If
Next I
rng.Delete 'then brutally erased from leaf
End Sub
```

Thank you very much in advance !

Further questions :

1) Is there a way to keep the downloaded excel hidden ?

I have :

```
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

xlApp.Visible = False

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\" & [A2] & "\Downloads\Nuance Mobility JIRA.xls")
```

But if i use x= *xlApp*.Workbooks.Open it gives me an error 'subscript out of range' and highlights :

```
Set sht = Sheets("general_report")
```

I tried doing

```
Dim xlApp as Excel.Application)
...
Set sht = xlApp.Sheets("general_report")
```

But it gets more errors

2) More generally, is their a way to keep the focus on my workbook (A), so that when chrome downloads the workbook (B) the chrome window doesn't pop up in front ?

Comment: What happens exactly when you run the routine in `A` for `B`? I am pretty sure that the problems are caused by the use of non-qualified objects (ranges, sheets etc).

Comment: @A.S.H Basically, the excel file I download has tons of columns I don't want (and the number of columns can change depending on which user runs the code), so rather than deleting all the columns individually, I just keep the columns that contain a specific header (key, summary, status) and delete the other columns. I have no error messages when running my codes, i just need to implement or call the removeColumns() sub in A/for B

Comment: Put the code into an XLAM file instead, and then add it to Excel as an Add-In, and then make sure to qualify what workbook/worksheet you are processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing, occurs because you dont directly address the needed worksheet/workbook, you rather always use the `Selected` worksheet, which you shouldn´t. It´s unclear and can be done just as simple if directly referring.

To refer to the `worbookB` I added a parameter to the sub `removeColumns`, so you can pass the needed workbook.

In the sub then, you just need to use the reference wherever you are working with the worksheet.

So instead of just writing:

```
somVariable = Cells(1,1).Value 'This always refers to the 'Selected' worksheet
```

You have to write:

```
someVariable = myWorkbook.myWorksheet.Cells(1,1).Value

'or to use the parameter wb like i did in your code:

someVariable = wb.Sheets(1).Cells(1,1).Value
'Here the first sheet of this workbook will be used

'You also can use the 'With' statment here:
With wb.Sheets(1)
    someVariable = .Cells(1,1).Value 'Note the dot in font of the 'Cells'
End With
```

---

So to use this knowledge in you example, you should try to alter code like following:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

xlApp.Visible = False
xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\" & [A2] & "\Downloads\Nuance Mobility JIRA.xls")

Set x = xlApp.Workbooks(1)

Call removeColumns(x)

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

---

```
Sub removeColumns(ByVal wb As Workbok)

...    

'Always when you are referring to the workbook, you have to use the reference passed as parameter
wb.Sheets("general_report").Rows("1:3").Delete
'In you code the first three rows will always be deleted from the 'Selected' sheet and not the one you are working on later, the 'general_report'
...

Set sht = wb.Sheets("general_report") 

'Also don´t activate() sheet here, youst directly refer to it later
'sht.Activate 'all the work in the sheet "Incidents"

'You can directly refer t it over the variable you created, like this:
c = sht.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
'From A1 to the left at the end, and then store the number
'of the column, that is, the last column

j = 0 'initialize the var
For I = 1 To c 'all the numbers (heres is the columns) from 1 to c
    headName = sht.Cells(1, I).Value
    If (headName <> Key) And (headName <> Summary) And (headName <> Status) Then
    'if the header of the column is differente of any of the options
        j = j + 1 ' ini the counter
        If j = 1 Then 'if is the first then
            Set rng = sht.Columns(I)
        Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, sht.Columns(I))
        End If
     End If
Next I

rng.Delete 'then brutally erased from leaf
End Sub
```

Hope I could help and if something is still unclear **feel free to ask**.

Comment: Thank you so much, that totally worked ! It never crossed my mind to reference directly to it (I have near 0 knowledge of VBA or coding, I just learn as I go creating tools for work by finding what I can on internet) :)

Comment: No Problem, not directly referring is a common beginner mistake. Just make sure to use as less `.Select` or `.Activate` as possible, and try to write you code as clear and direct as possible (even though this might be a ltittle more code).  :)

Comment: I have another more simple issue, how can i make it so that x can be used with the xlApp.Visible AND with the Call command ?                                                          
   Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

    xlApp.Visible = False
    
    Set x = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\" & [A2] & "\Downloads\Nuance Mobility JIRA.xls")
    
    Call removeColumns(x)

Comment: Please don´t write multiple lines of code in a comment, since thats pretty unclear, Just edit you question and put it under the already existing text with your further issue.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought I could put code in comments in the same format as above :s But I edited my question, you've done so much for me already, i hope you can help me out again ! If not no worries i'll make it work eventually :)

Comment: @L.P For 1): I edited the code, this may work, though i can´t test it right now. For 2): Since you´re opening chrome with the shell, maybe there is a way to hide or at least minimize the chrome window, but I have absoluteley no experience with this.

Comment: Mmh it triggers the same errors but it's a minor issue, i'll dig deeper myself :) thank you so much for your input and advice, I really appreciate the speed at which you replied and how you explained things for me :)

Comment: You're welcome mate, keep beeing curious and help others if you can. :)